# Tips for using Synapse or Gnome-do

Tags: 12.04, launcher, synapse

I have recently started using Synapse and Gnome-do as the applicaiton launcher on my Ubuntu 12.04.
Do you have any tips related to getting the best out of them?

Launching files and folders and applicaitons works well.
But I want some shortcuts to launch websites using these launchers so that i can just start type go.. and it suggests me google.com or so. OR any possibility of creating shortcuts of webpages. 
I know there are plugins which could call the firefox bookmarks but that doesn't seem to work or perhaps i dont know it :(

It was quite easy in TypeAndRun (of windows)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible(at least in synapse, I haven't checked this on Gnome-do yet). First you'll have to install a program called `alacarte`(and `synapse` of course). Then start alacarte and select the internet tab on the left-hand side pane. Then select "New Item". Set the type as application, name it however you want, and for the command, type this `xdg-open http://url.of.the.website.you.want`. Then click ok. You're done. Open up synapse and type in the name you chose for the launcher.

Comment: Interesting. Many launchers like this though (e.g. Kupfer, Launchbar) have built-in modes to let you work with your existing bookmarks. I don't know of any such feature in Synapse, though I'd use it heavily myself.